# remove_action() hook not working

Tags: hooks, child-theme

On my child theme,

I created this:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt',20);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt',30);
```

The `add_action` is working, but not the remove_action

What happens is, the `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` gets duplicated with the `add_to_cart` in the middle of the two.

I am using shopkeeper theme in woocommerce. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Actions (and filters) can be removed only after they had been set, therefor you will have to figure out when in the execution path the `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` is being added, and remove it only after that.